# Why FIFinderSyncController.isExtensionEnabled always returns false?

Tags: macos, findersync

I have a macOS app which uses FinderSyncExtension. From the MainApp, I'd like to know if FinderSyncExtension is enabled. For that, there is `isExtensionEnabled` class property in `FIFinderSyncController`, however it always returns `false`.

Does anyone know correct usage of `FIFinderSyncController.isExtensionEnabled` or in which case it would return `true`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works correctly for me when running OSX 11.6.1.  I'm using it just as you show,  `if !FIFinderSyncController.isExtensionEnabled {}`.

However, I'm just now investigating why I always get `false` on a system running OSX 12.2.

I'll probably go post on the Apple Developer forums, hopefully Eskimo will answer.